# Visual Studio how to undo click of Source Control / Git Global Settings / Diff Tool "Use Visual Studio"

Tags: git, visual-studio

I inadvertently clicked the "Use Visual Studio" blue text link next to Diff Tool in the Git Global Settings in VS 2022. Now, I'm stuck with VS ignoring my .gitconfig diff/difftool settings specifying BeyondCompare. I've tried every trick in the book to try to undo this action, even going so far as reset all my options to the default. Short of uninstalling/cleaning/reinstalling, is there any way to get VS to once again honor my .gitconfig settings?

[image: Screen shot of Diff Tool and Merge Tool settings]

I've tried:

1. Verified that global .gitconfig not changed - still has BC settings
2. Verified no local .gitconfig present
3. Set "Plug-in Selection" / "Current source control plug-in" dropdown to None and then back to Git
4. Reset all VS options back to default

None of these actions resulted in restoring the Diff Tool setting to "bc".

For clarity, let me share a snippet from my .gitconfig as well to illustrate that my diff and merge tools are configured correctly:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool "bc"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = bc
[mergetool "bc"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Git Bash type:

```
git config --global diff.tool bc4  (this will set the diff tool to BeyondCompare 4)
```

Another option is to specify the *path* to the `BComp.exe` through this  command:

`git config --global difftool.bc4.path "C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe"`

Comment: Thanks, but I already have BC set as my diff and merge tools in .gitconfig. VS used to use BC in response to my .gitconfig settings, but once I accidentally clicked that link in settings, it no longer uses BC for diff and refuses to let me correct the situation.

Comment: @JoelR.Hall Then probably VS is overriding the global gitconfig file. Did you use VS to create the git repo in the first place?

Comment: @JoelR.Hall Also try to replace `bc` in `tool` field with `bc4` in your gitconfig file  displayed in your question

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, I discovered what @Giuseppe mentioned in his comment above: clicking that blue button updated the local config to override my global config. You'd think VS would at least give you a hint as to the nature of the change brought about by their own button. Removing the override entry restored the "bc" setting which is what I wanted, however, I did have to exit and reenter VS before the options dialog showed the change.